# Android Studio Render Error for GIFs

Tags: android, gif

So I have been trying to upload gifs onto my application using Android Studio, and for some reason, 3 of the gifs upload correctly while 2 of them have a "Render Problem." I have all my gifs in the "drawable" folder. The first line of the error shows as

> java.io.IOException: AddStringToTable: codes: 4096 code_size: 12

Here is the block of code for one of the gifs that don't work:

```
    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:src="@drawable/geobreath"
         android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
         />
```

geobreath is the name of my gif.